# python code to test against multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Why doesn't this code produce intended output

```
for i in range(65,91):
  if result not in (chr(74),chr(75) :
   f=0
  else :
   f=1
```

Comment: `or` in Python is a boolean operator, not a conjunction; it does far less than the English conjunction `or`, and it doesn't do what you're trying to do there.

Comment: (Short circuiting isn't relevant at all here.)

Comment: The same property that allows short circuiting (`(True or x) == True`) leads to a slightly odd but useful behaviour: `or` returning one of its operands, not necessarily a bool. In this case it led to some confusion, as producing a bool wouldn't have led to any characters matching. Very few languages to multimatching in the way shown; I think Prolog might. In the example a regex `[IJ]` might have been more fitting.

Comment: How do i make this code correct ?